# Gebrauch von "-wert" gegenüber "-würdig"

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, usage

Gibt's einen deutlichen Unterschied zwischen den Wortendungen "-wert" und "-würdig"?

Wie z.B.: "bemerkenswert" oder "merkwürdig"

Ich spüre also dazwischen einen feinen Nuanceunterschied im alltäglichen Gebrauch, aber wie drückt man solches mit Worten aus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M.E. ist es eher die Ausnahme, dass die jeweiligen Begriffe so eng zueinander stehen, dass sie austauschbar wären. Beispiele:

> ein preiswürdiger Wettbewerbsbeitrag,

aber:

> ein preiswertes Angebot.

Bei "ehrwürdig" / "ehrenwert" wird das m.E. deutlich, wenn man versucht, den Kreis möglicher Objekte einzugrenzen. "Ehrwürdig" kann auch ein Gebäude sein, aber ehrenhaft bezieht sich m.E. immer auf Personen. Bei "bemerkenswert" / "merkwürdig" liegt der Unterschied in der Bewertung: ersteres ist neutral, zweiteres tendenziell abwertend.

Der wichtige Punkt dabei ist, dass diese Nuancen nicht an der Wortendung hängen, sondern am Gesamtbegriff. Daher denke ich nicht, dass sich für diese Wortendungen einheitliche Regeln finden lassen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Wortendungen sind in der Tat sehr ähnlich und oftmals beinahe gleichbedeutend.

z.B. "ehrwürdig" entspricht beinahe dem Wort "ehrenwert"

im Beispiel "bemerkenswert" (entspricht in etwa "besonders", "außergewöhnlich") und "merkwürdig" (entspricht in etwa "eigenartig") ist der Unterschied markanter.